# I cannot use RunWith in Java CucumberFramework

Tags: java, cucumber

See
[image]
First one

[image]
I could not take it here

Comment: Add code and error messages always as text, not as image

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. Please add code as (formatted) text to your question, instead of images. This will make it easier to answer your question.
2. Please make sure to use the same version for all Cucumber dependencies, to avoid collisions.
3. Make sure all dependencies are downloaded properly. (As an IntelliJ user, I cannot tell you how to do so in Eclipse.)